# Add a column to a dataframe based on the result of a schema validation

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm new to spark but have a bit of Scala experience. I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe based on the result of a validation method. Here's my code (that doesn't work):

a simple validator function to make sure row has the right number of elements:

```
  def isValidUDF(avroSchema: Schema): UserDefinedFunction = udf((row: Row) => {
    row.size == avroSchema.getFields.size()
  })
```

Here's where I use withColumn to add the column to the dataframe:

```
    val splitDF = df.withColumn("valid", isValidUDF(avroSchema)(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)))
```

This last snippet was provided to me and I don't completely understand what it's doing. I do know that if I hardcode the `isValidUDF` method to always return true (and not reference `row`) then the `withColumn` operation succeeds. As is, it doesn't work, I think because row isn't actually being passed to the method. I suspect it's the code `(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*))` that's tripping me up but can't quite figure out what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Here's some code to make this reproducible:

spark code:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import scala.util.{Success, Try}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

object ValidateSchema {

  // This appears to do nothing, and the debugger won't even stop here when placing a breakpoint on line 17.
  def isValidUDF(avroSchema: Schema): UserDefinedFunction = udf((row: Row) => {
    row.size == avroSchema.getFields.size()
  })

  // This will result in the print statement printing the table with an added column with 'true' values
  //  def isValidUDF(avroSchema: Schema): UserDefinedFunction = udf((row: Row) => {
  //    true
  //  })

  def splitDataFrame(df: Dataset[Row], avroSchema: Schema): (Dataset[Row], Dataset[Row]) = {
    val splitDF = df.withColumn("valid", isValidUDF(avroSchema)(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)))
    splitDF.collect().foreach(println)
    val valid = splitDF.filter(splitDF.col("valid") === true)
    val invalid = splitDF.filter(splitDF.col("valid") === false)
    (valid, invalid)
  }

  def validateSchema(session: SparkSession, dataUrl: String, avroSchema: String): String = {
    val parser: Schema.Parser = new Schema.Parser()
    val schema = parser.parse(avroSchema)

    val r: Try[(Dataset[Row], Dataset[Row])] = Try {
      val df = session.read.csv(dataUrl).cache() // TODO: don't assume Parquet
      splitDataFrame(df, schema)
    }

    val success = r match {
      case Success(_) => true
      case _ => false
    }

    val json = ("success" -> success) ~ ("validURL" -> dataUrl) ~ ("invalidURL" -> null) // TODO: set correct valid/invalid
    compact(render(json))
  }
}
```

Here's a unit test that can be used to run the code:

```
import com.bose.cdp.ingest.ValidateSchema._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.scalatest._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write

import scala.io.Source

class ValidateSchemaSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {


  val dataUrl: String = getClass.getResource("/sample.csv").getPath
  val jsonFile: String = getClass.getResource("/testSchema.json").getFile

  "validateSchema" should "validate the schema" in {
    val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("ValidateSchemaSpec")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    val schema = jsonToMap(Source.fromFile(jsonFile))
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    validateSchema(sparkSession, dataUrl, write(schema))
  }
}
```

Here's the schema input file, which can be saved to a file `testSchema.json`:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ticker",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "open",
      "type": [
        "double",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "close",
      "type": [
        "double",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "adj_close",
      "type": [
        "double",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "low",
      "type": [
        "double",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "high",
      "type": [
        "double",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "volume",
      "type": [
        "int",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "type": [
        {
          "logicalType": "timestamp-micros",
          "type": "long"
        },
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "topLevelRecord",
  "type": "record"
}
```

Here's the sample data, which you can save as `samples.csv`:

```
FLWS,6.03999996185303,6.3600001335144,6.3600001335144,5.94999980926514,6.40000009536743,495400,2003-01-07
MHF,7.19000005722046,7.23999977111816,6.34415292739868,7.17000007629395,7.26000022888184,72700,2015-08-11
RAVN,1.5,1.5,0.13375885784626,1.5,1.5,4800,1998-09-17
GOOGL,719.419982910156,727.200012207031,727.200012207031,718.869995117188,728.929992675781,1441100,2016-07-11
BAC,5,5,0.400442719459534,4.96875,5.015625,351200,1985-05-03
WFC,6.625,6.625,1.91186189651489,6.59375,6.6875,508000,1993-08-30
XOM,4.375,4.421875,0.119127497076988,4.328125,4.421875,5900800,1981-06-19
FLWS,11.1499996185303,10.8900003433228,10.8900003433228,10.1499996185303,11.25,138400,2002-07-01
GTS,12.3500003814697,11.2299995422363,11.2299995422363,10.9399995803833,12.3500003814697,168000,2009-02-26
RAVN,27.8799991607666,27.9500007629395,24.9132537841797,27.6499996185303,28.2299995422363,47700,2012-10-16
54,6.875,7.0625,3.47661709785461,6.875,7.0625,181400,1989-02-16
JPM,thirteen,13.1666669845581,4.27230453491211,12.9583330154419,13.2916669845581,2749200,1993-06-17
OXLC,18.1000003814697,eighteen,5.40552186965942,18,18.1299991607666,7300,2011-07-18
GOOGL,189.579574584961,185.680679321289,true,191.096099853516,11658300,2006-05-18
APOG,5.25,5.375,3.09623336791992,5.25,5,44600,1993-05-21
CCNE,7.5,7.5,2.32148718833923,7.5,7.5,2000.56,1997-08-04
AHH,15.5100002288818,15.3500003814697,15.3500003814697,15.2299995422363,15.5500001907349,382100,Sept 9th 2018
```

Here's a build.sbt to hopefully make helping easier:

```
ThisBuild / organization := "com.bose"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0"

suppressSbtShellNotification := true

val spark = "org.apache.spark"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.2"
val sparkCore = spark %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
val sparkSql = spark %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
val sparkAvro = spark %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion
val sparkDependencies = Seq(sparkCore, sparkSql, sparkAvro)

val json4s = "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3"

val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % "test"

lazy val ingestInferSchema = (project in file("ingest-infer-schema"))
  .settings(
    name := "ingest-infer-schema",
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies,
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest
  )

lazy val ingestValidateSchema = (project in file("ingest-validate-schema"))
  .settings(
    name := "ingest-validate-schema",
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies,
    libraryDependencies += json4s,
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest
  )
```

Comment: please add the exact error to the question

Comment: A reproducible snipped would also help! :)

Comment: @MarsellusWallace thanks for your response! Reproducibility resources added. :)